# How to add values to vector in map C++

Tags: c++, multimap

I have `multimap<string,vector<int>,int> hello` . I'm trying to `insert` a value to `hello`, but I have an error saying `No matching member function for call to 'insert'`

I think there's a problem with vector part, but I can't figure out what it is exactly.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

void addSpace(string &gendata, string &target){
    int size = static_cast<int>(gendata.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        target += gendata[i];
        // check i for (i < gendata.length() - 1) !!!
        if (i < gendata.length() - 1 && isdigit(gendata[i]) && isalpha(gendata[i + 1])){
            target += ' ';
        }
    }
}

std::vector<int> make_vector(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    std::vector<int> result;
    result.push_back(a);
    result.push_back(b);
    result.push_back(c);
    result.push_back(d);
    return result;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    multimap<string,pair<string,int>> student;
    multimap<string,vector<int>,int> hello;
    multimap<string,pair<string,int>>::iterator itr;
    string s, gendata, target, word, name, subject;
    int mark=0, i=0;

    target = "Aurora Physics 55 Lily Biology 81 Dylan Physics 62 Bella Physics 58 Jaxon Physics 85 Noah Chemistry 98 Jaxon Mathematics 54 Michael Chemistry 98 Charlotte Mathematics 92 Penelope Mathematics 95 Ellie Physics 93";

    istringstream iss(target);

    int count = 0;
    while(iss >> word){
        if(count == 0){
            name = word;
            count++;
        }
        else if (count == 1){
            subject = word;
            count++;
        }else if (count == 2){
            mark = stoi(word);
            student.insert({name,{subject,mark}});
            count = 0;
        }
    }

    string rememberName;
    int bio=0, phys=0, chem=0, maths=0, sum=0;
    for (itr = student.begin() ; itr != student.end() ; itr++) {
        bio=0; phys=0; chem=0; maths=0;

        rememberName = itr->first;
        while (rememberName == itr->first) {
            if (itr->second.first == "Biology") {
                bio = itr->second.second;
            }else if(itr->second.first == "Physics"){
                phys = itr->second.second;
            }else if(itr->second.first == "Chemistry"){
                chem = itr->second.second;
            }else{
                maths = itr->second.second;
            }
            itr++;
        }
        itr--;
        sum = bio+phys+chem+maths;
        // this is where I have a problem 
        hello.insert({rememberName,{make_vector(bio,phys,chem,maths)},sum});

    }
}
```

I'd like it to insert the vector into `hello` map.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is `hello` representing? Could it be that wanted to declare it like this instead `multimap< string, pair<vector<int>,int> > hello;`?

Comment: Could you trim the code down to a [mcve]? You probably just need a hardcoded value to insert in order to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I think it's a good attempt to produce an MCVE for a first post @JaMiT, but yeah xqoa, try to do what JaMiT suggested next time. :) However, I strongly feel that your declaration of the multimap is wrong, so focus there instead of the insertion method.

Comment: @JaMiT I'll look into that next time. Thank you.

Comment: @gsamaras Thank you for a warm welcoming :) yeah.. I found out that my `multimap` have declared wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration of `hello` is wrong. You cannot have three types in relation to each other here.

Looking at the documentation, [`std::multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) has 4 template arguments:

- `Key`
- `T` (a.k.a. value type)
- `Compare` - the type on which `operator()` will be invoked to compare elements of the map. Must be a functor type (function pointer, lambda, class with overloaded `operator()`). Defaults to `std::less<Key>`
- `Allocator` - not interesting for us.

When you declare `std::multimap` like this:

```
multimap<string,vector<int>,int> hello;
```

you're telling compiler it should compare keys by `int`s. This doesn't make any sense - when inserting or looking for elements in map, compiler will have to try to call `int(std::string, std::string)` and expect a result of type `bool` and this is not posssible.

---

Why do you want to store an additional `int` here? You can calculate it anytime from the `vector` you have in map. Best solution IMHO would be to not repeat yourself and use `std:multimap<std::string, std::vector<int>> hello`

If you really want to store `sum` as well as `vector`, you have to mash them into one type somehow. You could use `std::pair<std::string, std::pair<std::vector<int>, int>>`, but this gets pretty deeply nested. You could also `push_back` sum as the last element of the vector for exaple, but that makes the vector purpose pretty unclear (some values there represent grades and one of them is sum of the grades?)

Comment: I tried `multimap<string,vector<int>> hello;` and add the last value as a `sum` and it works perfectly! thank you very much for help.